# How do i send a post with json string as parameter and post via Alamorfire or URLSession in Swif 5 IOS

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, post, alamofire

please check the images of the code [struct image][1], [code image][2]

[post man Image][3]

I could post this complex struct on the server. While post the data it goes as Array. I have also tried to send JSON string as a parameter but failed.

```
struct MainNewRideModel: Codable{
    let data:NewRideModel
}
struct NewRideModel: Codable {
    var rideDetails: [RideDetail]
    var rideCoordinates: [RideCoordinate]
}

// MARK: - RideCoordinate
struct RideCoordinate: Codable {
    let latitude, longitude, time: String
}

// MARK: - RideDetail
struct RideDetail: Codable {
    let mobile: String
    let startaddress, endaddress: String
    let distance, avgspeed, maxspeed: Double
    let startTime, endTime: String
    let endbyuser: Int
}
```

This is upladed code but still fails

let dataObj = NewRideModel(rideDetails: rideDet, rideCoordinates: rideCode)
let finalObj = MainNewRideModel(data: dataObj)

```
        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        let jsonData = try! jsonEncoder.encode(dataObj)
        let json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        print("json \(json)")
        let dicJson = convertStringToDictionary(text: json)
        print("came")
        
        guard let dic2 = dataObj.dictionary else { return}
        print("No \(dic2)")
//            guard let dic3 = rideCode.dictionary else { return}
//            print("No \(dic3)")
        let parameters: [String: Any] = ["data": dic2]
        
        print(parameters)
     
AF.request("http://apps.acibd.com/apps/yrc/syncdata/bikeridesync",method: .post,parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ]).response { response in
        debugPrint(response.debugDescription)
        
        if let res = response.value{
            if let finalData = res{
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(finalData)
                print(swiftyJsonVar.error)
                print("Here")

               
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

}

```
extension Encodable {
  var dictionary: [String: Any]? {
    guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else { return nil }
    return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)).flatMap { $0 as? [String: Any] }
  }
}
```

Tried changing parameter:

```
     let parameters: [String: Any] = ["data":
                                             [
                                                "rideCoordinates": [["time":"1621849394.64643","longitude":"90.3770315654824","latitude":"23.80106560200154"]
                                                ],
                                                "rideDetails": [["mobile":"01755939896","startaddress":"100.00m (speed -1.00 mpsBangladesh Standard Time","distance":0.10000000000000001,"endTime":"2021-05-24 15:43:27","endaddress":"Bangladesh Standard Time","avgspeed":0.10000000000000001,"maxspeed":1.1000000000000001,"endbyuser":1,"startTime":"2021-05-24 15:43:12"]]
]
        ] as Dictionary
```

**OutPut:
parameter : ["data": ["rideCoordinates": [["time": "1621849394.64643", "longitude": "90.3770315654824", "latitude": "23.80106560200154"]], "rideDetails": [["startaddress": "100.00m (speed -1.00 mpsBangladesh Standard Time", "endTime": "2021-05-24 15:43:27", "distance": 0.1, "endbyuser": 1, "mobile": "01755939896", "endaddress": "Bangladesh Standard Time", "maxspeed": 1.1, "startTime": "2021-05-24 15:43:12", "avgspeed": 0.1]]]]**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gB67.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hizwb.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOt9t.png

Comment: Copy/paste code, not only screenshot. And edit your question with that code (formatted please), it's unreadable in comments.

Comment: In POST, usually params are inside the `httpBody`, not in the URL. You are looking for that example I guess: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#request-parameters-and-parameter-encoders

Comment: As Larme says, please put your code (With code tags) in your question. , and flag the lines that are generating errors. Screen shots are very hard to follow. And do not put more than a few words of code in comments. Comments don't allow line breaks or formatting, so code in comments is VERY hard to read.

Comment: Updated code this aslo fails

Comment: No Error shows in compilation but response data returns an error. Tried with postman works fine there

Comment: `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` and you encode with `JSON` protocol? That doesn't make sense. Can you give the documentation of your API, and/or give the Postman configuration? Did you know that Postman can generate Swift code that can be the hint to see what's wrong with your code? "but response data returns an error" What error does it return? Do we have to guess? Is there an important information on that error on why it fails?

Comment: In header it is using default one ie. "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". Please Guide how to encode in this case

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOt9t.png

Comment: encoding: JSONEncoding.default. what encoding should i replace with?

Comment: while trying to conver struct to dictionary it appears ["data": ["rideCoordinates": <__NSArrayI 0x280821620>( .....

Comment: i have converted successfully to String JSON in swift controller. now how should i post this JSON via Alamorfire

Comment: if i set json string as parameter. i find a error Argument type 'JSONParameterEncoder' does not conform to expected type 'ParameterEncoding'

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `Encodable` type already, you can use the `encoder` version of the Alamofire call, not the `encoding` version.

```swift
AF.request("http://apps.acibd.com/apps/yrc/syncdata/bikeridesync", 
           method: .post, 
           parameters: parameters,
           encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default)
```

However, if you want URL form encoded parameters, as your manually added `Content-Type` seems to indicate, you'll need to use the `URLEncodedFormEncoder.default` as the `encoder`. Both encoders will add the appropriate `Content-Type` for you automatically.

Comment: didn't work for me. do i need to changing anything in struct for encoding as i desired?

Comment: You probably just need to match your type's property names to what the server expects.